# To which Sobolev local space Dirac delta function belongs to?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I have found that Dirac delta function 
$\delta (x)\in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}), \forall s<-\frac{1}{2}$, and Heaviside function $\in  H^{s}(\mathbb{R}) , \forall s<\frac{1}{2}$;

Also i want to use the following formula for Cauchy principal value $p.v\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$:
$\hat{H}(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \delta(\xi)-\frac{i}{\pi}p.v\left(\frac{1}{\xi}\right) \right )$
in order to find to which $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$ does $p.v\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ belong?

How can I derive it using this formula?
Or what is another way to find to which $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$ does $p.v\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ belong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've edited your LaTeX a bit. I have to wait till its reviewed. However, I did not change $ p.v $ to $ p \cdot v $. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Ahaan Rungta Yes I meant p.v (principle value).Thanks!

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know. I'm a bit of a newbie in this stuff, so yeah.

Comment: You just need to use the definition of Sobolev, in terms of tempered distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can just compute the Fourier transform of $p.v.\ 1/x$ directly:
$$\int_{\epsilon<|x|<\epsilon^{-1}} \frac{1}{x} e^{-ikx} = -\pi \operatorname{sign} k \tag1$$
Indeed, the contribution of $\cos kx$ is zero, and the improper integral of $\frac{1}{x}\sin kx$ is a well-known one.

The function $(1+k^2)^{s/2}(-\pi \operatorname{sign} k )$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ if and only if $s<-1/2$. Hence, $p.v.\ 1/x$ is in $H^s$ if and only if $s<-1/2$.

Using the relation with Heaviside function  $H$ amounts to something similar (after all, (1) is very close to a Heaviside function), but there is an added complication because $H$ does not have zero mean. This is why you get a delta function in $\widehat{H}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how can I find to which $H_{loc}^{s} p.v.(\frac{1}{x})$ belongs ?

Comment: @Lilly Same values of $s$. The membership in $H^s_{\rm loc}$ is determined by integrability of $|k|^s \hat f(k)$ in a neighborhood of infinity (because the part of Fourier transform supported on a bounded interval corresponds to a real analytic function).

Comment: Thanks a lot!If I understood you right in order to check to which $H_{loc}^{s}$ function $f$ belongs I need to check if $\int \left |k  \right |^{s}\hat{f}(k)dk< \infty$? But in this case we get $-\pi \int \left |k  \right |^{s} sign(k)  dk$ and this integral converges for $s<-1$, and not for$s<-\frac{1}{2}$. Can you tell me what is my mistake, please?