# The Heaviside Function, its Fourier transform, and its inclusion in $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ for all $s<1/2$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, fractional-sobolev-spaces

It seems from what I read that the Heaviside function is in $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $s<\frac{1}{2}$. See for example [To which Sobolev local space Dirac delta function belongs to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472104/to-which-sobolev-local-space-dirac-delta-function-belongs-to).

It seems it makes no sense for two reasons. The first is that is not localized in any way (that is not even squared-integrable on $\mathbb{R}$)

Furthermore, if we follow the procedure, one way to decide if a functions $f$ is in $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ is to check if $(1+\omega^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}(\omega)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

We have that
$$\hat{H}(\omega)= \pi \delta(\omega)- \mathrm{PV}\left(\frac{i}{\omega}\right).$$
So it is not true that $(1+\omega^2)^{s/2}\hat{H}(\omega)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$
for all $s<1/2$ because of the Dirac Delta function.

It seems like people will check the condition on the signum function instead, as its Fourier transform is
$$
\widehat{{\text{sign}}}(\omega)=-\mathrm{PV}\left(\frac{2i}{\omega}\right).
$$
Thus it checks the condition if and only if $s<1/2$.

My question: what do people mean by saying that the Heaviside function is in $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$  for all $s<1/2$? Maybe is that those spaces admit discontinuous functions? Indeed, $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a space where each function can be made continuous. So that would mean that this property is lost as soon as $s$ is less than 1/2? Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: See the title of the question you linked: it belongs to the **local** $H^s$ space. Perhaps this is of interest as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825303/proof-that-the-characteristic-function-of-a-bounded-open-set-is-in-h-alpha

Comment: The Sobolev space $H^s$ (for $s\geq 0$) is contained in $L^2$ by definition. Since the Heaviside function is not square integrable, the best you can expect is that it's locally in $H^s$ as Calvin Khor mentioned.

Comment: @Calvin Khor Thank you. That question you cite and the answer you posted there are exactly what I was looking for. .